# *ngFor firing all colums on one click angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

```
<tr *ngFor = 'let student of students>
<td  contenteditable="true"  class ='phone' #button>
{{student.phone}}
<i (click)='showbox()' class = '    glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i>
<input *ngIf='showinput' type="text"   
   class="phone form-control required email "  style="height:38px;">
</td>
</tr>


showbox(){
  this.showinput = true;
}
```

Here when ever I click on `<td>` it should open input tag but on one click it opens for other columns also. Can anyone suggest help?

Comment: Put the showInput flag in the student object, since each student can be opened independantly. A global flag can't be used to do that.

Answer (score 1):

showinput variable is declared in the context of the component.

So when you click the td tag the value of the variable is changed correctly, but since the context is the component it affects every td in the component.

If you want the variable to only affect the one td then use the student variable for context.

```
<td  contenteditable="true"  class ='phone' (click)='showbox(student)' #button>{{student.phone}}
         <input *ngIf='student.showinput' type="text" [(ngModel)] = 'student.phone' class="phone form-control required email " style="height:38px;">
    </td>
```

Component:

```
showbox(student) {
    student.showinput = true;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the change,i edited my code with a function,how to display the individual with calling function?Can you pls check it.

Comment: @vak yes, it is: http://plnkr.co/edit/3feKZvILIh4DD4E5COOX?p=preview. If you want help, you'll need to provide more details than just "it's not working".